# Proper time of an accelerating particle

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, observers

I am supposed to find the proper time of a particle whose worldline is given by:
$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{3}{2} a t^2\\
y(t) &= 2 a t^2\\
z(t) &= 0
\end{align}$$
where $a = const$ and $0 \leq t \leq t_0$ for some $t_0$.

I found $\gamma (t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{25 a^2 t^2}{c^2}}}$.

To find the proper time $\tau$ I calculated this:
$$
\begin{align}
d \tau = d \left(\frac{t}{\gamma}\right) &= \frac{\gamma dt - t d \gamma}{\gamma^2}\\
&=\frac{\gamma- t \frac{d\gamma}{dt}}{\gamma^2}dt
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = \frac{\beta^2}{t} \gamma^3$ I got:
$$
d\tau = \frac{1 - \beta^2 \gamma^2}{\gamma} dt
$$
Using the condition $\beta < 1$ I got the constraint $t_0 < \frac{c}{5a}$.

Now I calculate $$\tau_0 = \int_0^{t_0} d\tau = t_0 \sqrt{1- \frac{25 a^2 t^2_0}{c^2}}$$
I am puzzled by this result because when I plug in the value of $t_0$ I get $\tau_0=0$.

I am not sure how to interpret this result. Is my line of thinking correct? If it *is* correct, how do I make physical sense out of this?

Comment: Using the *correct* formula $d \tau = dt \sqrt{1-v(t)^2/c^2}$ could be helpful.

Comment: @Hyperon Then why should I not take the derivative if $\gamma$ is dependent on $t$ through $v(t)$? Should I also not take the $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ when calculating 4-acceleration? If not, why?

Comment: 1. As $ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 - d\vec{x}^2$ is an invariant, you have $ds^2 = c^2 d \tau^2$ implying $d \tau = dt \sqrt{1-\vec{v}(t)^2/c^2}$ for your problem. 2. I have not the slightest idea what you mean by "4-acceleration" in this context. 3. The concept of "proper time" can be found in all relevant text books.